# How to generate encrypted password for HTTP POST?

Tags: java

I'm working on a java project in which i need to login to a site & for that i supposed to post the data to the server. After analyzed HTTP POST traffic with fiddler, i found that the site is encrypting the password with some hashing algorithms. i.e. username posted as plain text, but password is altered. I checked the javascript source which is used for the encryption. I don't know how to generate the same encrypted text from the given password. How to do this?

Comment: No, its not hacking. I just need to login to the site where i need to upload my file. For that, i need to login to that site. But as its kind of altered from original, i need to do the same. Thats y i asked this question here.

Comment: Register an account with that site, pass your username and password to your JAVA with some method (like cURL in PHP) and do whatever you like.

Comment: But how could it be right? It seems like they are using SHA algorithm & generating the encrypted text with the password. So is there any way for me to generate the encrypted text by executing the script with java?

Comment: I guess they should pass the actual password to that function & generating the unique encrypted text for each user.  So how can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't reverse a string hash by `Hash Algorithms`. Benefit of Hash Algorithm are:

- result of hash algorithms is a `fixed-size`.
- result can't reverse for achieve original string.

you can read more information in blow links:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function